# How to calculate for each row the order of column value by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| - | date_x | date_y | date_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-19 12:26:48+00:00 | 2021-02-19 16:15:21.510000+00:00 | NaT |
| 1 | 2021-02-19 16:16:54+00:00 | 2021-02-10 17:44:01+00:00 | 2021-02-11 10:10:01+00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-02-21 16:17:54+00:00 | 2021-02-20 17:44:01+00:00 | 2021-02-15 10:10:01+00:00 |

and I want to calculate for each row the order of each column by row:

| - | date_x | date_y | date_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

To then get the average order of each column for the whole dataframe:

| - | date_x | date_y | date_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1,33333333333333 | 0,666666666666667 | 0.5 |

I tried using pandas `Series.argsort()` but it's the same as `Series.sort_values()` but instead returning indexes not values.
I then thought of iterating each row and looking up the index of the list provided by sort_values but I'm sure there MUST be a faster and cleaner solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), subtract 1, get `mean` and convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
df = df.rank(axis=1).sub(1).mean().to_frame().T
print (df)
     date_x    date_y  date_z
0  1.333333  0.666667     0.5
```

Comment: @LeleCanfora - Are there datetimes? Or strings? What return `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Yes that's the fastest and cleanest solution, there's even no need to subtract 1. Thanks

Comment: @LeleCanfora - Absolutely agree.